# Regex, How to match some character but must with some other character existed?

Tags: python, regex

What I want to do is implement a simple auto localization tool, the tool will check all Chinese characters and replace them with some keys.

There are some rules:

1. matched text must between `"` and `"`
2. matched text must contain Chinese, which Unicode range is `[\u4e00-\u9fff]`
3. matched text could contain alphabet, number or punctuation, let's simple it to could contain `[a-z]`
4. there is no restrict in their orders

Let's say `"我很nice"` and `"你好"` will match, but `"hello"` will not match.

So, how to write the regex in python to achieve that?

`ur'"([\u2000-\u206f\u3000-\u303f\u4e00-\u9fff\ufb00-\ufffd\w]*[\u4e00-\u9fff]+[\u2000-\u206f\u3000-\u303f\u4e00-\u9fff\ufb00-\ufffd\w]*)"'` will do the math.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service. We'll be happy to help you when you have specific programming related problems, but not when you have a task you need to complete, and you're too lazy to do it yourself.

Comment: @abccd Do I just ask for code? I just ask for a simple regex that I can't deal with, any wrong with this?

Comment: Yes. You hadn't shown us any attempts on solving the problem yourself, all you have is some rules to follow and a request to write a regex. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: The tool's code is complex, and the core issue of that is the regex itself if I don't do any search, how could I know Chinese character is in the range [\u4e00-\u9fff]? Don't judge me, I hate lazy people on this site too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write regex like this -

```
"\w*[\u4e00-\u9fff]+[\u4e00-\u9fff\w]*"
```

Comment: Your answer gives me some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match any text that contains any Chinese character in it, you can use `search(..)` method on the compiled regex object.

```
import re

words = ["我很nice", "我n很i你c好e", "你好", "hello", "好", "abcd", "ㄱㄴ"]

regexp = re.compile(r'[\u4e00-\u9fff]')

for word in words:
    if regexp.search(word):
        print(word)

# prints:
# 我很nice
# 我n很i你c好e
# 你好
# 好
```